# understand c logic printf & valuables

Tags: c, forms, program-entry-point

I am trying to understand the logic behind the `printf` numbers in the code below. Can someone explain how the valuables change? What symbol is executed first (`||` , `&&`, `!=` and so on)? In which direction is it executed?

```
#include <stdio.h>
static float w = 3.9;
short
f (short a, short *b)
{
  a++;
  (*b)++;
  w++;
  printf ("13: %d %d %4.2f\n", a, *b, w);
  return a - *b;
}

int
main ()
{
  short x, y, z, arr[] = { 4, 8, 0, 6 }, *p = arr;
  char m[] = "dcrfvtgb", *pc;

  y = 2;
  z = 3;
  x = (++y != z);
  printf ("1: %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

  x = y = 6;
  x *= (y = 5);
  printf ("2: %d %d\n", x, y);

  x = 0;
  y = 2;
  z = 7;
  printf ("3: %d %d %d %d\n", !x || y && !z, x, y, z);

  x = 5;
  y = 3;
  printf ("4: %d %d %d\n", x, y, x < y ? x : y);

  y = 0;
  if (y)
    x = 7;
  else
    x = 5;
  printf ("5: %d %d\n", x, y);

  y = 8;
  if (z = (y++ > 8))
    x = 9;
  else
    x = 0;
  printf ("6: %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

  x = y = 5;
  while (y++ < 5)
    x += y;
  printf ("7: %d %d\n", x, y);

  for (x = y = 5; y < 7; x = y++)
    printf ("8:%d %d\n", x, y);

  for (x = 2, y = 5; y >= 1; x++, y /= 3);
  printf ("9: %d %d\n", x, y);

  printf ("10: %d %d\n", p[2], *(arr + 1));

  x = y = 3;
  z = f (x, &y);
  printf ("11:%d %d %d %4.2f\n", x, y, z, w);

  for (x = y = z = 10; z-- > 9; x *= y);
  printf ("12: %d %d %d\n", x, y, z);

  for (pc = m; *pc; pc++)
    (*pc)--;
  printf ("14: %s %c\n", m + 2, *(m + 1));

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This covered in detail and in better detail than here. You will get a better understand as well

Comment: 'valuables'?  perhaps you mean the more common term: 'variables'

Answer (score 0):

The `printf` function takes a format string as the first argument, then zero or more other arguments. Each of the things beginning with `%` in the format string correspond to one of the other arguments. At least the way you are using it, these are in the same order, so the first `%` placeholder corresponds to to the second argument (i.e. the first after the format string), the second `%` placeholder to the next and so forth. The letter following the `%` (and sometimes other characters) describe the type of argument and how it is to be printed. See the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) for `printf()` for more information.

Each of the arguments is evaluated before the call to `printf`. The C standard does not specify the order in which the arguments are evaluated. So if you have (e.g.), `!x || y && !z` as an argument, each of those will be evaluated prior to the call to `printf()`. For the order in which the components of those are evaluated, see [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B).

Note that that only tells you what order operators are evaluated in (i.e. in `x + z * y`, this says the `z * y` is evaluated before the `+`). It doesn't tell you whether `x`, `y` or `z` will be evaluated first; as they may be expressions themselves, that's important. So, for instance in:

```
int
f(int a, int b, int c)
{
    return g(a) + h(b) * i(c);
}
```

in the general case you have no guarantee in which order `g(a)`, `h(b)`, and `i(c)` are evaluated. You only know the order in which the `+` and `*` are evaluated.

If you want to know more about evaluation order, you need to research [sequence points](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point).

Comment: And how each line in the program makes its equations? Thank you!

Comment: I'm not going to go through the whole program for you. You've got quite enough to go on now!

Answer (score 0):

@abligh says "The C standard does not specify the order in which the arguments are evaluated."

As far as I know, the Intel implementation pushes the arguments right-to-left onto the stack, which means that the arguments are evaluated right-to-left.

```
printf ("12: %d %d %d\n", x, z, z++);
```

In this example the first value of z, when printed, will be one higher than the second value of z when printed.